# Как растянуть видео в css?

Tags: html, css

Доброй ночи. Как растянуть видео на весь блок ? что бы между блоками осталось расстояние (1050-2*515). Через html получается , но нужно через css

```
https://codepen.io/camobap6/pen/BajaQNV
```

```css
.video__iframe{
  width: 515px;
    height: 316px;
    
  }
  .video__iframes{
    width: 1050px;
    height: 316px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
  }
.video{
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
div{
  border:solid red 1px;
}
.title {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 78px;
    font-size: 52px;
    width: 55%;
    margin:  0 auto 0 auto;
    z-index: 2;
    
  }
```

```html
<section class="qwer">
  <div class="title"> Заголовок</div>
<div class="video__iframes">
    <div class="video__iframe">   
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z53GUVrMvIE"  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    
    </div> 

    <div class="iframe">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/anWk4Pa5u8A"  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
   
    </div>
  
</section>
```

Comment: `iframe{
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}` так может быть ?

Comment: Не знаю почему , но не работает

Comment: iframe растянулся же щас или нет ?

Comment: нет, не растягивается

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/Yzwzpgv - смотри

Comment: Правый блок не расятгивается

Comment: Я извиняюсь , я должен был в павом блоке записать video__iframe  не доглядел. Спасибо все работает.